# facebook like box embed google chrome

Tags: facebook, firefox, google-chrome, facebook-like

i'm having a little troubles with the facebook "Like Box"... It is not showing up in google chrome... This started two or three days ago and i would like to know what it's going on...
Can anyone help? It seems to work fine in Firefox

Regards,
Tiago Castro

Comment: Your page link to check?

Comment: but you can check other pages too... i think it is happening to many people... http://www.wordpressthemeshock.com/ here is another one, but this is not mine

Comment: Hello my dear it is showing in my google chrome

Answer (score 1):

That started to happen with me when i installed Facebook disconnect. Check if u are using some extension in Chrome browser.